# Iterating an Array Inside Object

Tags: javascript

Please, can someone tell me what I'm not doing right. I was actually trying to iterate over
this array and get all the values to the console but  was just getting the first index

```js
var all_tips = new Array ();
var paid_amount = [];
var Bills ={
    bill_array: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
    tips: function calculate(){
       for(num of Bills.bill_array){
           return num
       }
        }
    
}
console.log(Bills.tips())
```

Comment: You call `return`, the function (and the loop inside it) is no longer executed

Comment: Ciao, as @Harun Yilmaz said, the iteration will be executed just one time. Is incorrect to say "is no longer executed".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are `return`ing the value from the loop which means in the first iteration, the function will `return` and terminate.

You need to move `console.log()` into the loop. Also you can use `this` reference instead of `Bills` inside the function.

```js
var all_tips = new Array();
var paid_amount = [];
var Bills = {
  bill_array: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
  tips: function calculate() {
    for (num of this.bill_array) {
      console.log(num)
    }
  }

}
Bills.tips();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, try this:

```js
var all_tips = new Array ();
var paid_amount = [];
var Bills ={
    bill_array: [124, 48, 268, 180, 42],
    tips: function calculate(){
       return Bills.bill_array;
        }
    
}
console.log(Bills.tips())
```